# Java Scanner with URLConnection

Tags: java, web

I have problem with reading text form InputStream connected with the URL.
I'm using Scanner to read text but it looks like there were no text formating.

Here is code

```
 connection = new URL(finalURL).openConnection();
 connection.connect();
 inStream =  connection.getInputStream();
 in = new Scanner(inStream);
 while(in.hasNextLine()){
   line = in.nextLine();
   System.out.println(line);
}
```

I have omitted try catch clause.
The output is some like this:
µtÂ÷BPv§2d
ŐüUŘ}ĎÓăR

While it shoud be like this:
06MAGNA,20121109,0.26,0.27,0.25,0.27,37820
08OCTAVA,20121109,0.73,0.75,0.73,0.73,12244

When I have saved it on disk as txt file and then use Scanner it works fine but via URL it doesn't. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Post the code you use to write on disk, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its happening because of charset different in the input stream and default charset of scanner. Try passing the `Charset` in the `Scanner` constructor.

```
         in = new Scanner(inStream, "UTF-8");//set the appropriate charset
```

**EDIT:** You can get content encoding using `connection.getContentEncoding()`.

Update your scanner instantiation as:

```
         in = new Scanner(inStream, connection.getContentEncoding());
```

**EDIT1:** To deal with `gzip` input stream, use `GZIPInputStream` as below:

```
      inputStream = new GZIPInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
```

Comment: @JacekKurlit: I didn't mean to use `UTF-8`(it was just an example). Use the charset of your input resource.

Comment: How can I check it?
It's somewhere on website that provides this URL?

Comment: @JacekKurlit: Updated the answer. Please check.

Comment: I have iterated over Charset.availableCharsets()  and used each one as parameter in Scanner constructor but it didn't work. None of Charsets helped.

Comment: connection.getContentEncoding() returned null and also threw 
 java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException: gzip
  Do I need to somehow add this Charset to my jre?

Comment: @JacekKurlit It means its returning you the compressed content using gzip. You need to use `GZIPInputStream`. I am updating the answer in a minute. Please try.

Comment: I just changed  in = new Scanner(new GZIPInputStream(inStream)) 
Now it's working fine. Thank you so much!

Comment: @JacekKurlit Yes, I update the answer with similar details. Please don't forget to accept the answer.